# Polynomial calculator values not being saved correctly

Tags: c, polynomials

The quof,exp, and var are returning nonsense ints what am i doing wrong?
Also im in need of a fuction to derivate the polynomial

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    char poly[50];
    int quof[10];
    int exp[10];
    int contquof=0, contexp=0, contvar=0, i=0;
    char var[6];

    printf("Introduza o polinómio\n");
    scanf("%s", &poly);

    for(i=0; poly[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
      if(isalpha(poly[i-1]) && isdigit(poly[i]))
      {
           exp[contexp]=poly[i];
           contexp++;
      }

      if(isdigit(poly[i]))
      {
        quof[contquof]=poly[i];
        contquof++;
      }

      if(isalpha(poly[i]))
      {
        var[contvar]=poly[i];
        contvar++;
      }
      for(i=0; i<2; i++)
      {
          printf("%d\n", quof[i]);
          printf("%d\n", exp[i]);
          printf("%d\n", var[i]);
      }
      return 0;
   }
}
```

An example of input : 2x⁴+3y so values should be stored like 2,3 -> quof[0],[1]    x, y -> var[0], var [1]  4 -> exp[0]

Comment: With `for(i=0; poly[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
      if(isalpha(poly[i-1]) ...` code is already lost as code attempts `poly[0-1]` which is outside array bounds,  `scanf("%s", &poly);` should be `scanf("%49s", poly);`  (no &)

Comment: Is `"2x⁴+3y , 2,3 -> quof[0..."` the true input? or is input only `"2x⁴+3y"`?  Is input using `⁴` or `4`?

Comment: @chux nono, the input is 2x⁴+3y and yes we must use ⁴ instead of 4 but it must be read as 4

Comment: To use ⁴, which encoding do you use?

Comment: for the input-> 2x²+3x⁴
output-> 2
1804171096
x
3
32749
x